# Display limited no. of videos on page load

Tags: php, jquery

On my page Load no of videos displays. No limit. In one row 4 video display. Now I want to show only two rows. rest of rows will be display on button click

This is my div when video data is display

```
<div id="lightbox" class="row filteredVideoContent">
        <?php 
            foreach ( $aVideo as $oVideo )
            { ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 photography app" id="load_data">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <!-- <div class="hover-bg"> -->
                        <div class="">
                            <a href="#video_container" data-backdrop="static" class="video_thumb" data-toggle="modal" data-videopath="<?php echo $oVideo['videoPath']; ?>" data-videosubject="<?php echo $oVideo['videoSubject']; ?>">
                                <div class="hover-text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $oVideo[ 'videoSubject' ];?>">
                                    <h4> <?php echo substr($oVideo[ 'videoSubject' ],0,20); ?> </h4>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                    if( ! empty( $oVideo[ 'videoThumb' ] ) )
                                    {
                                        $thumbName = $oVideo[ 'videoThumb' ];
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $thumbName = "assets/video/common.jpg";
                                    }
                                ?>
                                <img style="height:188px;width : 263px"
                                     src="<?php echo base_url () . $thumbName ?>" class="videoThumb img-responsive"
                                     alt="<?php echo $oVideo[ 'videoSubject' ];?>">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div>Uploaded By : <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $oVideo[ 'userName' ];?>"> <?php echo substr($oVideo[ 'userName' ],0,20);?> </span></div>
                        <div>HQ : <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo @$oVideo[ 'hq' ];?>">  <?php echo substr(@$oVideo[ 'hq' ],0,20);?> </span></div>
                        <div>Subject : <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $oVideo[ 'videoSubject' ];?>">  <?php echo substr($oVideo[ 'videoSubject' ],0,20);?> </span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Honestly, what kind of answer are you expecting to get here? You've shown no effort and no code. How is anyone supposed to help you?

Comment: @Jai: I wonder if the "asap" and "urgent" phrases in some questions is a cultural norm, and is thus does not sound impolite, say in Indian English. I tend to just edit them out if I see them.

Comment: @halfer i didn't meant that but before asking a question one should think that people here at SO only can help when you help them by posting your code which is not worked. English is not my native language so if that sounds rude i would remove it.

Comment: @Jai, thanks, I agree. For reference, I'd say ASAP/urgent are not rude exactly in native English, but they sound rather demanding, given that it is volunteers who are helping `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are looking for js/jquery solutions, as I can see the jquery tag I am suggesting you a solution with jQuery:

First, I want to clear that you have a php for each loop which is generating same ids again and again. This is the `div`:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 photography app" id="load_data">
```

You can remove the id attribute or make it dynamic by appending some indexes to it. So what you can do is:

In CSS:

```css
.lightbox.row{
  display: none;
}
.lightbox.row:nth-child(1),
.lightbox.row:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

Hide all the container div with the css above but first and second.

Now in jQuery you can do this:

```
$('#showAll').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.lightbox.row').filter(':hidden').show();
});
```

---

And another suggestion is to remove the id from `row` and put that in classlist:

```
<div class="lightbox row filteredVideoContent">
```

and this one too:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 photography app load_data">
```

Comment: this works but only 2 video it display not 1st two row an you tell me what change i can do

Comment: @KimJones Well with the css only first two will be displayed and when you click on showall button/link the hidden ones will be displayed.

Comment: ok u mean 1st two content or video will display not whole 1st row right?

Comment: okay! clear one thing `portfolio-item` is this your row or this one `photography`

Comment: @kimJones okay! i get it the div wrapper with class `row` is your row right.

Comment: asking for whole row? than <div id="lightbox" class="row filteredVideoContent"> this div give all video data. and photography will display one video

Comment: If you are generating rows dynamically then you need to change its id too because each element in a page should have unique id, same ids creates issues.

Comment: Ok thank you so much

Comment: Height issue I face.. It will Hide all videos initially and than display videos. So height will take of all content and load more button display after all video. And Above solution not display all video.. It Only display load more button